# SQL reset AUTO_INCREMENT when DELETE statement empties table

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, auto-increment, mysql-8.0

i need to create a trigger when a DELETE command on a table is launched.

i have some problems on my code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER reset_AutoIncrement 
AFTER DELETE ON table1 
FOR EACH ROW 
ALTER TABLE table1 AUTO_INCREMENT = 0;
```

I want to reset AUTO_INCREMENT value when

`mysql> DELETE * from table1.`

Only when the command is called to empty **the entire table**.

When i try to create this trigger the following error returns:

`ERROR 1422 (HY000): Explicit or implicit commit is not allowed in stored function or trigger.`

I'm working on mysql CLI. Not workbench or similar.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Use `TRUNCATE table1;` instead of DELETE. This will re-seed the autoincrement.

Comment: You cannot issue an alter table statement from a trigger, since any ddl statement will automatically commit the current transaction and this is not allowed in a trigger. You cannot use trigger to achieve what you want. Perhaps bundling delete and the alter table in a stored proc would be acceptable to you.

Comment: @Akina Cannot truncate a table referenced in a foreign key constraint (`database`.`table2`, CONSTRAINT `value`)   :S

Comment: so remove also the foreign key first and after truncating add it again